# Opencart get value of certain order totals code title separately

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart, e-commerce

It might be a complicated question which I'm so for, I've been knocking my head for days with no solution and even Google didn't find me an answer for that. In opencart you have a Table in database named "order_totals" structured as below:

[image]

By default Opencart comes with a Model function that returns the Order Total based on order Id let's say `order_id = '1'`

```
public function getOrderTotals($order_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order");

    return $query->rows;
}
```

So if you compare the function with the attached image of the database it should return  4 items "sub total, shipping rate, payment, total" that's clear when seeing `order_id` and `order_total_id`

My question how am I able to get `value` of specific `code` to list them in a View table separately as following

[image]

Normally we can add the filtering code the SQL query to return the requested value 
For example if I want the `value` of `code` `shipping` I can use the below code:

```
public function getOrderTotals($order_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT value FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total WHERE code = 'shipping' AND order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order");

    return $query->rows;
}
```

This will return the value needed for Shipping in case of order id 1 of our example it be

> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(6) "5.0000" } }

That's great however to get the value of shipping, sub_total, payment and total, I need to create multiple functions separated which I don't find it an efficient solution.

How's it possible to get the `value` of each `code` separately and list them in the Admin View Dashboard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the expected results directly with SQL by using *conditional aggregation*.

Consider:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'sub_total'         THEN value END) sub_total,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'shipping'          THEN value END) flat_shipping_rate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'payment_based_fee' THEN value END) payment,
    MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'total'             THEN value END) total
FROM order_totals
GROUP BY order_id
```

If you need to filter on a specific `order_id`, you can add a `WHERE` clause to the query.